# Get bluetooth service and characteristic from SPP UUID

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, android-bluetooth

I am using the plugin **cordova-plugin-bluetoothle**.

I want to subscribe to a device whose SPP UUID is `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` (a well-known SPP UUID according to the official [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)) )

However, with the plugin cordova-plugin-bluetoothle we need to have the service's UUID and the characteristic's UUID to [subscribe to the device](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#subscribe).

I tried as follow:

```js
const params = {
    address: this.device_address,
    service: '00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
    characteristic: '00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
};

return this.ble.subscribe(params);
```

But I then I get the error `Service not found`

I would like to know how could I get the service and the characteristic from the SPP UUID?

Comment: In my understanding, the Bluetooth SPP is a Bluetooth Classic profile, not a Bluetooth Low Energy one. Please scan your device using a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to make sure. If my assumption is correct, the plugin you are using is the wrong one. Try something like [cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial)

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer, indeed, it was not a BLE ^^..